# Problems getting Jar file to link correctly. Verify Errors

Tags: java, android, exception, jar, verifyerror

I've been searching the web for a long time, and it seams that this VerifyError isn't that uncommon and can have multiple reasons for tripping. I have created a project, that I've exported as a jar file. It is built with android 2.2 (API 8). This part works fine. But I have a separate project that when I try to import it, I start having problems.

The only way I've been able to get it to work, is to import the jar into a libs folder I created. It then get's automatically added as an Android Dependency and I can use it fine, however I can't attach my javadoc file to it, and in my build configuration it says I can't modify the dependency. (Can't link to a javadoc).

What I thought I should be able to do is simply add it as an external jar, then link the javadoc and source. If I do this, the code that uses the jar shows no errors, and the javadoc comments work. However I keep getting a VerifyError when I run it.   I've attached a stack trace that shows the errors. I'm completely out of ideas, does anyone have any suggestions? Am I building the jar file wrong? Am I importing it wrong?

If anyone can help point me in a constructive direction, it would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Stack trace:
[image: Stack Trace]

Comment: In case it is added as an external jar, make sure the jar files are also marked as exported, in `Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export`.

Comment: This comment definitely pointed me in the right direction to go. I just found the solution. I'll add it in below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this was frustrating to solve. The solution took about 20 seconds when I spent over an hour researching the problem.

What I had to do was go to:
Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export

But rather than just clicking the external jar, I had to move it up to the top of the list for the build path order.

Credit definitely goes to yorkw for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Android jar files are a little different. 
You could try putting the JAR files into the Android "dx" tool
It's in the ~/android-sdk/platform-tools

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I found the solution. Cheers!